# Is it possible to train a sklearn model (eg SVM) incrementally?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, logistic-regression

I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis over the twitter dataset "Sentiment140" which consists of 1.6 million labelled tweets . I'm constructing my feature vector using Bag Of Words ( Unigram ) model , so each tweet is represented by about 20000 features . Now to train my sklearn model (SVM,Logistic Regression,Naive Bayes) using this dataset , i have to load the entire 1.6m x 20000 feature vectors into one variable and then feed it to the model . Even on my server machine which has a total of 115GB of memory , it causes the process to be killed .

So i wanted to know if i can train the model instance by instance , rather than loading the entire dataset into one variable ?

If sklearn does not have this flexibility , then is there any other libraries that you could recommend (which support sequential learning) ?

Comment: If the data does not fit in the memory you may think about decreasing dimensionality via PCA or word2vec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really necessary (let alone efficient) to go to the other extreme and train instance by instance; what you are looking for is actually called *incremental* or *online* learning, and it is available in scikit-learn's [`SGDClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) for **linear** SVM and logistic regression, which indeed contains a [`partial_fit`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit) method.

Here is a quick example with dummy data:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)

clf.partial_fit(X, Y, classes=np.unique(Y))

X_new = np.array([[-1, -1], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])
Y_new = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1])
clf.partial_fit(X_new, Y_new)
```

The default values for the `loss` and `penalty` arguments (`'hinge'` and `'l2'` respectively) are these of a [`LinearSVC`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html), so the above code essentially fits incrementally a linear SVM classifier with L2 regularization; these settings can of course be changed - check the docs for more details.

It is necessary to include the `classes` argument in the first call, which should contain all the existing classes in your problem (even though some of them might not be present in some of the partial fits); it can be omitted in subsequent calls of `partial_fit` - again, see the linked documentation for more details.

Comment: Is the classes (classes=np.unique(Y)) only for this particular slice of data ? or does it have to be the whole set of classes stored somehwere?

Comment: @desertnaut: Can you explain what is meant by **instance by instance training**

Comment: @aspiring1 it simply means one sample (instance) at the time