# Incrementally fitting sklearn RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm working with a environment that generates data at each iteration. I want to retain the model from previous iteration and add new data to the existing model.
I want to understand how model fit works. Will it fit the new data with the existing model or will it create a new model with the new data.

calling fit with the new data:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
for i in customRange:
    get_data()
    clf.fit(new_train_data) #directly fitting new train data
    clf.predict(new_test_data)
```

Or 
Saving the history of train data and calling fit over all the historic data is the only solution

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
global_train_data = new dict()
for i in customRange:
    get_data()
    global_train_data.append(new_train_data)  #Appending new train data 
    clf.fit(global_train_data) #Fitting on global train data
    clf.predict(new_test_data)
```

My goal is to train model efficiently so i don't want to waste CPU time re-learning models.

I want to confirm the right approach and also want to know if that approach is consistent across **all classifiers**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second approach is "correct", in the sense that, as you have already guessed, it will fit a new classifier from scratch each time the data is appended; but arguably this is not what you are looking for.

What you are actually looking for is the argument `warm_start`; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html):

> **warm_start : *bool, optional (default=False)***
>
> When set to `True`, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble, otherwise, just fit a whole
>   new forest. See the [Glossary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-warm-start).

So, you should use your 1st approach, with the following modification:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, warm_start=True)
```

This is not necessarily consistent across classifiers (some come with a `partial_fit` method instead) - see for example [Is it possible to train a sklearn model (eg SVM) incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54722861/is-it-possible-to-train-a-sklearn-model-eg-svm-incrementally/54723127#54723127) for the `SGDClasssifier`; you should *always* check the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thank you, so i take other classifiers will also most probably create completely new classifiers and hopefully they will have some provision to retain previous model

Comment: @SachinHegde As I said, there is no standard - the documentation is always your best friend